# multiple actions inside foreachRDD in Spark

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

I am a bit confused on how Spark jobs work. I have use case where Spark is running two jobs for same batch, and hence doubling the time to execute the data for that batch.
For e.g. i am simplifying my code, and writing that as below. I have two Spark actions inside foreachRDD.

But obviously, ONLY the second action will be executed as the first action is inside the if clause(which is false).

But i can see in the Spark UI, that for every batch, there are two jobs running and hence doubling the time to execute the data in the batch. 
And just to verify if i remove the first action and the if clause, the number of jobs reduce to one.

So, isn't spark smart enough to make out the if condition? , and just looks at the number of actions defined in the foreachRDD block?
as you can see the below image, there are two jobs 1322, 1323.
If i go inside these jobs , they both are running the second action.

[image: Spark UI showing two jobs for same data]

```
JavaInputDStream<ConsumerRecord<String, String>> messages = ....

messages.foreachRDD(rdd - > {
if(false){
  rdd.count();
}

rdd.count();
});
```

Comment: are you running a spark streaming job?

Comment: yes , its a spark streaming job